# Shortest path in directed graphs with no more than $\log \log n $ negative edges

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=n$  vertices and some weight function $w\colon E\to \mathbb{R}$,
I also know that there are at most $\log\log n$ negative weight edges in $G$, and $G$ does not have any negative cycles.

> Find minimum cost path from $s$ to $t$

My try so far:

I know that just running Bellman–Ford will be too naive, I thought generating a new
$w'$ function like Johnson's algorithm does:

Something like removing any step 1 negative $e=(u,v)$
and running Dijkstra from $s$ as (single source shortest path) and $t$ (as single destination)
after doing it for each edge $e$ total $\log\log n$ times, I can use shortest path as the function of
$h$ like Johnson's algorithm, and it will run in $O(\log\log n \cdot n \log n)$

I'm struggling with the proof of correctness for this function $w'$, and I'm not sure if my runtime is optimal as well.

Comment: This [negative weight edge graph construction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/146237/4249) works in your case where you create $\log \log n$ copies of the graph and then run Dijkstra's algorithm on that.  Then you'll have $N = n \log \log n$ and the running time $O((N+m) \log N)$.

Comment: thanks ! i think its will work , and what you mean in $m$ (run time)?

Comment: $m$ is typically referring to the number of edges.  I think you might be able to use some dynamic programming to keep it $O(m)$ for the _original_ $m$, and not the number of edges in the created graph.